# shinyloadtest with multiple different users

Tags: r, shiny, load-testing, rstudio-server

I'm working now on testing load of Shiny application deployed with RStudio Server Pro. The app uses PAM authorization and currently allows to log in for around 20 users.

For simulations, I'm using `shinyloadtest` package.

Inside shinyloadtest tool [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/articles/load-testing-authenticated-apps.html#load-testing) I found how to run tests with passing user credentials, but this allows me to pass only one login and password. As a result I'll simulate many sessions logging as the same user. Is there possibility to run simulations logging as different users?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is not.

However, there's no value in a simulation including multiple users if the application behaves the same for all of them. There is no inherent additional overhead if the users accessing the application are different.

If your application doesn't behave the same way for all of your users — for example, if your application inspects `session$user` and displays a different UI depending on the user name — then it might make sense to perform one simulation per "type" of user recognized by your app.